# MySql like operator for selecting all the records not working correctly in Mobile devices

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, ipad, zend-framework

```
    $table->select()->where("(`{$searchTableName}`.`title` LIKE ? || `{$searchTableName}`.`description` LIKE ? || `{$searchTableName}`.`keywords` LIKE ?)", "%{$text}%");
```

Here is my code.'$text' is the variable specifying the keyword that we are going to search.When I run the above code and inspected it ,the preview will look like below.

```
  SELECT `engine4_core_search`.* FROM `engine4_core_search` WHERE ((`engine4_core_search`.`title` LIKE '«b%' || `engine4_core_search`.`description` LIKE '«b%' || `engine4_core_search`.`keywords` LIKE '«b%'))
```

Here I used the keyword 'abb'.But in query it appeared as '«b'.What may be the reason for stripping the first two characters and the '%' operator? This happens only when I try to select all the records containing the specific keyword. Also it works correctly in web. The issue comes only in the case of Mobile devices like Iphone and Ipad..Please help me.

Comment: are you using a particular framework?

Comment: Yes.I am using zend framework.

Comment: maybe you need to escape `$text` before directly injecting it

Comment: what do you mean by escaping $text here?can u please explain?

Comment: for example if you have a search string like this: `hello%string`. you have to escape those: `hello\%string`. i haven't used zend yet so you'll have to look for that function that escapes strings

Answer (score 0):

If you a re using `jQuery-mobile` (because issue is in mobile device).
In some cases `jQuery-mobile` may produce this kind of issues.
Try without `jQuery-mobile` .